# Create loop over Excel ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a function which loops over certain cell values. If the value contains an `"X"`, the count should increase by 1.

The syntax should be something like this:

```
 Sub CountVars()

 Dim range As Variant
 Dim ranges As Variant

 Dim count as Integer

 'set array with ranges
 range = Array("c3", "f3", h3)

 For Each range In ranges

   count = 0
   'if range = "X" then
   count = count + 1
   End If    
 Next
```

But I cant get this working. Any thoughts on how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your ranges within the `Range()` function directly. No need for a string array. For example:

```
Dim r As Range, count As Long

For Each r In Range("C3,F3,H3")
    If r.Value = "X" Then count = count + 1
Next
```

Note that string comparison done this way is case-sensitive. If you need to check for `x` or `X`, you can convert to the same case or use a function like `StrComp()` with the `vbTextCompare` parameter.

```
If UCase$(r.Value) = "X" Then ...
' or
If StrComp(r.Value, "X", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ...
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your code gives me a compile error: (wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Comment: On which line? I don't see any issues here.

Comment: it gives an errror right at the start where I declary my funcion ->  Sub cDays()

Comment: Are you attempting to pass a parameter to your `Sub`? Because you haven't defined any.